# Excel formula that checks adjacent cell and if certain text, it uses the value of a 3rd cell, otherwise it returns N/A

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365

In my spreadsheet, I have 4 columns:

A - Location

B - Report Date

C - Status

D- Review

I need a formula to enter into cell D3.  If C3 equals "Not Completed", it will take the value of cell B3 (report date).  If cell C3 equals "Completed", I want D3 to show N/A

```
=IF(C3=”Not Completed”,B3,N/A)
```

Any assistance that you can provide will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: `N/A` should be in quotes

Comment: If you want the #N/A use `NA()`

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions (as commented above) to this. First add quotes around the N/A. Second use NA().

```
=IF(C3="Not Completed",B3,"N/A")

=IF(C3="Not Completed",B3,NA())
```